# Options for making C immune to buffer overflows and other errors?

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

Is there anything that makes C provably immune to buffer overflows (EDIT: <s>and other errors that arise from C being commonly compiled unchecked</s> i.e. probably some kind of bounds checking)?  And also is compatible enough to be used on large production code (EDIT: to be used on everything)?

I tried gcc with mudflap and it allowed this to run without error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2];
    a[-1] = 5;
    printf("%u\n", a[-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

So it seems mudflap is incomplete like the others I've tried and only makes exploits less probable. Also it appears aimed at debugging not production use. I'm wondering about provable unexploitability. It can be done. Any thoughts on why it hasn't been and in common use everywhere? A minor performance hit (even 10x slower, but probably 2x slower) seems like a small price to pay for the billions if not trillions of dollars in damages this class of bug exploit allows.

EDIT: To clarify:

By 'buffer overflow', I mean not the programmer having code allowing an overflow, but the compiler allowing memory outside the target variable/array/(m)allocblock to be written (or read) by it (like: int a,b; *(&b-1) should be caught by the compiler and not just be a).

By 'prove', I mean colloquially as in "old simple Pascal does not allow buffer overflows with close enough to 100% certainty that we could say it is proven", and although it may use system functions that aren't safe, if they were written in a bounds checking Pascal too then they wouldn't have overruns either. I used the word "prove" to distinguish from the various imperfect hardening tools.

And by 'exploitability' I mean 'buffer overflow exploitability', which is a simple problem that is solved in other languages at the expense of speed and memory.

"Are you serious? If it existed, we'd already do it." - this is what I was curious about. The technology is here - fat pointers (the C standard allows compilers to make pointers any size) with full per pointer bounds checking. But I can't find anymore than proof of concept, discussions, and papers about it, when what I want is a full C compiler that does this and an entire Linux distribution built with it. No one is going to rewrite everything (Linux, Apache, etc...) in a safer language anytime soon (and sadly they keep writing new stuff in C), but we can make C/C++ safer and recompile everything. At least for uses that need security above all else.

Comment: You actually *can't* prove "unexploitability" of *any* program. You might be able to prove it about your own code, but unless you make the compiler, all the compile-time and run-time libraries, the operating system, and the hardware yourself, there is no way to prove that there isn't an exploitable problem anywhere. And even then you have the problem of [trusting trust itself](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf).

Comment: *Also it appears aimed at debugging not production use* - it has to be. If code allows buffer overflow it means it's faulty and needs to be fixed.

Comment: "*I'm wondering about provable unexploitability. **It can be done**.*" Can it now?

Comment: you could also try clang with `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=address-full`, but there's only so much you can do with C; you might want to look into other languages, eg Cyclone or Rust

Comment: *"Is there anything that makes C provably immune to buffer overflows?"*.... yes, there is. It is well known to every Sr. Programmer, but its just that we are all too lazy to do it.  In truth, we kinda enjoy watching systems get hacked and our hard work get screwed up by script kiddies.  ***Are you serious?  If it existed, we'd already do it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various solutions to this problem that leave the C language largely alone. Mostly what they do is track "dangerous" pointer accesses (those that a static analysis cannot demonstrate is safe) at some runtime cost.

See

- [Region-based memory management in Cyclone](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=512563) defines a C-like language. (Research)
- [An efficient and backwards-compatible transformation to ensure memory safety of C programs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1029913) claimed to operate on full C (Research)
- [Memory safety without runtime checks or garbage collection](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=780743) works for a subset of C (Research)
- [SoftBound: highly compatible and complete spatial memory safety for C](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1542504) with a claimed overhead of 67% (Research, but an [alpha version for LLVM is available](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~santosh.nagarakatte/softbound/)).
- [CheckPointer - A C Memory Access Validator](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6065175&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6065175), that diagnoses memory access errors in heap, stack and threads, for full C. Commercially available from my company, see bio.  [It will have no trouble diagnosing your toy program].

You could argue, of course, that all of these are solutions that compile C "checked", which you seemed to object to in your question.  I see these as just another step in the build process in the worst case.

The real problem is these solutions all have measurable overhead in time and space.  When building embedded systems, that extra cost shows as real dollars spent on getting a somewhat more expensive processor to get the work done in the allocated time, and/or extra memory for tracking troublesome pointers.  Most manufacturers, when choosing between the perceived low probability of a bad program (or more blackly, "nobody will notice till I've sold all these!"), and the absolutely real additional cost, will tend to optimize cost and now you are back to compiling raw C programs without the runtime checks.    "Cheap" compromises "quality" or "schedule".  We see it in airline seat comfort, and in software safety.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - the state of the art of this kind of thing.  A miscommunication about "checked" - I was saying that C without checking has buffer overflows... I was assuming that all full solutions to this are in fact 'checked'.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as long as you're willing to give up a few things:

- pointer math
- unchecked 3rd-party libraries (kinda ruins the point, no?)
- null-terminated C-strings

You'd just need to roll your own allocator and deallocator to write the size of each allocation to a header, then use a macro for pointer/array lookups to check against that allocation size:

```
void *myalloc(size_t size) {
    if (size == 0) return NULL;
    void *data = malloc(size + sizeof(size_t));
    if (data == NULL) return NULL;
    *((size_t *)data) = size;
    return data + sizeof(size_t);
}

void mydealloc(void *data) {
    free(data - sizeof(size_t));
}

#define item(data, index) ({ \
    __typeof__(data) item_data = data; \
    __typeof__(index) item_index = index; \
    assert(item_index >= 0 && (item_index + 1) * sizeof(*item_data) <= *((size_t *)((void *)item_data - sizeof(size_t)))); \
    *(item_data + item_index); \
})
```

Any string functions would need to use the size_t value written to the header, rather than looking for a null byte. You should be doing that anyway since null terminators make no sense in a Unicode world. It's also possible to check stack allocations in the same item() macro, but I think it'd have to be platform- and implementation-dependent.

The reason you don't see this more often is because if you're willing to accept the significant performance hit, **it'd make more sense to use a higher-level language that has those guarantees *built-in*** along with a ton of other nifty language features.

Answer (score 0):

We can't fix C, so to deal with known hazards like this one is the responsibility of the professional programmer. The advantage with C is that it's been around forever, so all weaknesses, pitfalls and poorly-defined behavior are well-known and documented.

What you can do to prevent bugs like these:

- Set the compiler to be as picky as possible. In case of GCC for this specific bug, it doesn't seem to help... supposedly there's some options called -Warray-bounds and -fbounds-check, but these don't seem to work at least not in GCC 4.9.1/Mingw64. Anyway, you can catch numerous other common bugs by always compiling with `std=cxx -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.
- Use a static analysis tool. These should at least be able to find all compile-time bugs related to bounds checking.
- A cheaper alternative to external tools is to use defensive programming. In this case you could have caught the bug with asserts. For example:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define ARR_SIZE 2
  #define INDEX -1

  int main()
  {
      _Static_assert(INDEX < ARR_SIZE, "Array index too large.");
      _Static_assert(INDEX >= 0,       "Array index too small.");

      int a[ARR_SIZE];
      a[INDEX] = 5;
      printf("%u\n", a[-1]);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  And you can even catch runtime bugs similarly with runtime `assert()` in the debug build of the project. This also saves a lot of time during program development, as you find the bugs quicker.
- General measures to improve code quality: code reviews, coding standards etc.